# By hovering the element extends and cover another one

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I want to make it thats when you hover the input, the input extends to the full length of the div covering the whole span - i tried different option but they just dont work.

```css
* {
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 330px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#input1 {
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 70px;
  transition: .8s;
}

#input1:hover {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="span1">what do you have to do?</span>
  <input id="input1" type="text" placeholder="">
</div>
```

i would be so gratefull if you just tried do help

Comment: What do you mean by *"the input extends to the full length of the div covering the whole span"* - Do you mean the span disappears?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your goal correctly, then you can solve this problem by using `position: absolute;` on the `#input1`.

```css
* {
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 330px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
}

#input1 {
  margin-left: 35%;
  width: 70px;
  transition: .8s;
  position: absolute;
}

#input1:hover {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0px 15px;
}

.span1 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="span1">what do you have to do?</span>
  <input id="input1" type="text" placeholder="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```css
.container {
  width: 330px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#input1 {
  margin-left: 250px;
  width: 70px;
  transition: .8s;
  z-index: 10;
}

#input1:hover {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.span1 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="span1">what do you have to do?</span>
  <input class="input1" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="">
</div>
```